# RemoteService - restarts after closing the launching Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I'm blocked with this for a few days and can't find the answer on this.

I start a **remote service** from an Activity. After starting the service, I close the launching Activity.
I close the main Activity from the task manager like this: home_btn long press and the list of opened app appears and then swipe left on the main Activity.

**The thing that happens is that my service gets restarted! even thought it is a remote service, that has it's own process, doesn't depend on the launching activity!**

All the internal variables are going to be reset and I don't want that.

-I don't want to use useForeground() method because I don't want my service to be visible in Notification

I currently start a Remote Service like this and the service starts(I can see it in the menu Settings->Apps-> tab Running):

```
btnStartSrv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startService(new Intent("com.example.servicerst_tst.RemoteService"));                       
    }

});
```

android manifest xml looks like this:

```
<service android:name="com.example.servicerst_tst.RemoteService"
             android:process=":serviceTST" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.servicerst_tst.RemoteService" >
                </action>
             </intent-filter>
</service>
```

the service class:

```
public class RemoteService  extends Service{

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.           
      return START_STICKY;  
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  null;
    }

}
```

I'm seeing the service restarting or reseting .. in the DDMS. 
When closing main Activity the service disappears from the list in the DDMS and the gets started by itself in about 2 seconds. This can be visible in the service also. If you place some internal variables that get change during the life of the service. They will get reset, like the the service is restarting itself after closing the main Activity.

I just want my service not to reset, restart when I'm closing the main launcher Activity.
If the user closes the launcher Activity, from task manager or by his mistake, I want the service to run in background.

Am I doing something wrong here or missing something from my code to prevent restarting? 
Why is reseting the service?

Comment: Is it actually doing anything? Why are you concerned about it restarting? Any process can be shut down whenever the OS feels a need to do so (to save memory, power, etc).

Comment: At the moment it is not doing a thing, but you can put several things in it and restarts the same way.

I've tried to minimize the example with the simplest form of service.

I'm setting some variables in the service and starting also some threads, the result is the same as this simple form of service. I don't want the service to restart.
As I said, I don't want the users to close launching Activity from the task manager and restart my service.

How am I going to avoid this restarting issue?

Comment: Suppose the user reboots the phone. How are you going to prevent the service from being killed? Change the way you think about the problem. When your service exits, save state to permanent storage. When it restarts, load the state.

Comment: rebooting phone is one thing, restarting service on running phone is other.
it is too complicated to save the state, it will complicate the implementation.
All I want is not to restart the service when launching App is closed.

Comment: If you want your users to have a good experience with your product, then you need to handle the "complicated" scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

From [Android Developers - Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) : "if the service is declared to run in the foreground (discussed later), then it will almost never be killed. Otherwise, if the service was started and is long-running, then the system will lower its position in the list of background tasks over time and the service will become highly susceptible to killing—if your service is started, then you must design it to gracefully handle restarts by the system".

Declaring your service to run in the foreground has specific requirements: "A foreground service must provide a notification for the status bar, which is placed under the "Ongoing" heading, which means that the notification cannot be dismissed unless the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground." and "To request that your service run in the foreground, call startForeground()." I know you said you don't want it to be a foreground service, but you have to live with the parameters Android sets out for you.

Comment: ook , got it. From what I'm seeing I have to make it restart reliable! also use startForeground() if you want to be alive all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem with restarting service when launching Activity closes!
You should use startForeground() to not have this issue.
So startForeground() solved the restarting problem when closing launching Activity.
I've made also the service, restarting reliable.

Still I have a question..how the services ... like facebook and other big services run in background without any startForeground() implemented. 
Also they are not killed by the system and they run in background forever without any startForeground() implementation. they live forever in background. For sure is somehow possible.
Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

How to avoid notification but still implementing the startForeground() method:
This is done By implementing the notification without

.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)

for other details see

[How to correctly handle startForegrounds two notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029431/how-to-correctly-handle-startforegrounds-two-notifications)